# Can "DISTINCT" in a CYPHER query be responsible of a memory error when the query returns no result?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

working on a pretty small graph of 5000 nodes with low density (mean connectivity < 5), I get the following error which I never got before upgrading to neo4j 3.3.0. The graph contains 900 molecules and their scaffold hierarchy, down to 5 levels.

```
(:Molecule)<-[:substructureOf*1..5]-(:Scaffold) 

Neo.TransientError.General.StackOverFlowError
There is not enough stack size to perform the current task. This is generally considered to be a database error, so please contact Neo4j support. You could try increasing the stack size: for example to set the stack size to 2M, add `dbms.jvm.additional=-Xss2M' to in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation just add -Xss2M as command line flag.
```

The query is actually very simple, I use distinct because several path may lead to a single scaffold.

```
match (m:Molecule) <-[:substructureOf*3]- (s:Scaffold) return distinct s limit 20
```

This query returns the above error message whereas the next query does work.

```
match (m:Molecule) <-[:substructureOf*3]- (s:Scaffold) return s limit 20
```

Interestingly, the query works on a much larger database, in this small one the deepest hierarchy happened to be 2. Therefore the result of the last query is "No changes, no records)".

How comes that adding DISTINCT to the query fails with that memory error? Is there a way to avoid it, because I cannot guess the depth of the hierarchy which can be different for each molecules.

I tried the following values for as suggested in other posts.
    #dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
    #dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512m

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=4096m

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4096m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=4096m
```

None of these addressed the issue.
Thanks in advance for any help or clues.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Have you tested with 3.3.1 yet?

Comment: Also, what happens if you prepend the query with `CYPHER 3.2` ?

Comment: I haven’t tried with 3.3.1, but i did with 3.2.6, same issue. I will try with 3.3.1.

Comment: Is all you need from the query distinct :Scaffolds that have a :Molecule node at 3 :substructureOf traversals away? If so this might be easier addressed by a different query. Also, how many :Scaffold nodes and :Molecule nodes are there in your db?

Comment: Because this is a graph and not a tree, I need to first get the distinct scaffolds a 3 edge distance to hence start a query from these. This database is quite small as compared to others I play with, and not so dense. I have 1129 molecules, 882 scaffolds out of none are at 3 edge distance from the molecule. That’s where the bug is, if at least one scaffold would exist, the query would work. If not, DISTINCT generates a memory error.

Comment: This is fixed in head of 3.3 as of https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/10666. Will make it to 3.3.2. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the additional info, I was able to replicate this on Neo4j 3.3.0 and 3.3.1, and this likely has to do with the behavior of the pruning-var-expand operation (that is meant to help when using variable-length expansions and distinct results) that was introduced in 3.2.x, and only when using an exact number of expansions (not a range). Neo4j engineering will be looking into this.

In the meantime, your requirement is such that we can use a different kind of query to get the results you want that should avoid this operation. Try giving this one a try:

```
match (s:Scaffold)
where (s)-[:substructureOf*3]->(:Molecule)
return distinct s limit 20
```

And if you do need to perform queries that may produce this error, you may be able to circumvent them by prepending your query with `CYPHER 3.1`, which will execute this with a plan produced by an older version of Cypher which doesn't use the pruning var expand operation.